# IOS JSON parsing

Tags: ios, json, database

I am an iOS beginner. I want to test open source application UBER prototype . When I have launched successfully the application on my Mac  I have got the problem (signing up for this ) . I guess there is  a problem with data base settings .

Error :

> Failed to run command eventually with error: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with
>   array or object and option to allow fragments not set."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or
>   object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Could you give me advice how to fix it?  The link for the project is [here](https://github.com/RedFish/Uber).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set option value to `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments`. Maybe you have set something else!

Try to look something similar like this in your code:

```
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:contentOfLocalFile options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&deserializingError];
```

And please update the question with the `JSON` format you are getting?

Comment: Thanks Anurag . Could you give me a hint in which framework  folder it is ?

Comment: it looks I lack it

Comment: It depends! try to search `NSJSONSerialization ` in "Find Navigator". Let me download the project and check it.

Comment: It  doesn't help